# Controlling authentication redirects with JHipster, Spring Security, and oauth2

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

I want to be able control the automatic redirect to an oauth2 authorization server when the user is not logged in.

I generated a JHipster Gateway project, and the code below is simply a copy of that, with the addition of the `oAuth2ClientContextFilter` variable, which is `autowired`, and then I use it to `setRedirectStrategy`

However the variable is `NULL` when it comes time to use it. What am I doing wrong?

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration

public class OAuth2SsoConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final RequestMatcher authorizationHeaderRequestMatcher;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oAuth2ClientContextFilter;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuth2SsoConfiguration.class);

    public OAuth2SsoConfiguration(@Qualifier("authorizationHeaderRequestMatcher")
                                  RequestMatcher authorizationHeaderRequestMatcher, CorsFilter corsFilter) {
        this.authorizationHeaderRequestMatcher = authorizationHeaderRequestMatcher;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        oAuth2ClientContextFilter.setRedirectStrategy(new RedirectStrategy() {

            @Override
            public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String url) throws IOException {
                // My Code Here
            }

        });

    }

    @Bean
    public AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        return new AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler())
        .and()
            .requestMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(authorizationHeaderRequestMatcher))
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/profile-info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not good to mix autowiring strategies (field autowiring and constructor autowiring), because construction occurres prior to `@Autowired`. So either inject filter into constructor:

```
private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oAuth2ClientContextFilter;

public OAuth2SsoConfiguration(
    @Qualifier("authorizationHeaderRequestMatcher")RequestMatcher authorizationHeaderRequestMatcher, 
    CorsFilter corsFilter, 
    OAuth2ClientContextFilter oAuth2ClientContextFilter
) {
    this.authorizationHeaderRequestMatcher = authorizationHeaderRequestMatcher;
    this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
    this.oAuth2ClientContextFilter = oAuth2ClientContextFilter;
    .....
}
```

or move RequestMatcher & CorsFilter out of constructor arguments and denote them `@Autowired`

Comment: Just a note, if you use `@Autowired` fields (using the constructor is a [better choice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-collaborators)), you can use the `@PostConstruct` annotation for a method and it will be called when the fields get values assigned.